# authentication mechanism in one module overrides in another module zf2

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2

I have two modules authentication in one module somehow overlaps authentication in another module...hasIdentity method always returns true for the another module if authentication is succesful in one module and so the user can log in another module without being authenticated the same problems existes with logout logging out logs out from both the module....it appears that authentication service instance is being shared amongst the modules which is creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon for ZF2 authentication modules to store the authentication service in a key `authentication` or `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` inside the service manager.

If you are mixing two authentication modules inside your application you have to make sure you separate the authentication service logic properly.

Without more details it is impossible to advise you more. Read also [here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)